# How can I install the host command on a Yocto based system

Tags: networking, yocto

On my system `nsloookup` is installed. But I want to install the `host` command tool.

I haven't found the `host` Tool under receipes of openembedded.

Does I have missed something?
How Can I install the `host` tool on my yocto system?

Comment: host is part of bind so adding `bind-utils` to your image should help

Answer (score 0):

As the comment of jku:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " bind-utils"
```

will install the host Tool on the yocto image.